# Video stretched on iphone. How to loop movie

Tags: video-streaming, iphone, mp4

I have over 1000 flv clips for education market on server side.

Each clips plays for less than 3-4sec.

192x144 frame size.

They play on infinite loop.

Users access clips via web only - after logging into their account.

Our clients now wish to access them via iphone and similar. I will convert to mp4 for this to occur.

Issue x 2....

1. The iphone stretches the 192x144 clip to fit the iphone player. How can I make the clips play at native frame size on iphone - at 192x144?
2. Can I get them to play on infinite or three loops? I think not based on research so far, but if anyone has a solution that would be appreciated.

Issue number 1 is the priority.

Thanks in advance everyone.

J